# Samples of a single storm building wanted

Tags: rain, ambience, max-msp

I'm working on a max msp patch that will allow the transition from calm weather through to breezy/ light right right through to a heavy storm as part of some kind of "ambience engine".

I'm basically doing this by crossfading between samples of light rain, heavy rain, storms etc. But it's quite obvious that these samples were not recorded in the same place during the same storm so the transitions are jarring.

Are there any particularly good recordings of weather out there? Ideally one long recording of a real storm running its course.

Looking at the clouds outside my window it's a shame I don't have anything I could record with right now...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was in La Porge in France last week and there was an almighty storm which I was lucky enough to record for a couple of hours, I've not listened back to the recordings yet let alone edited, but would be happy to share them with you if you are interested, you might be able to get something interesting out if it.

Comment: That would be great, I'd love to get hold of that. What's the easiest way for you to share? @RedSonic01

Comment: @jbrittan - dropbox? send me a message via linkedin http://www.linkedin.com/in/richardlapington so I can get your email, then I'll send you a link ;)

Comment: Red Sonic - would i be able to get that edit too? I'm making a radio drama, and a building storm is needed

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but a perspective on it: if I had to construct what you describe for a film I could well imagine using a lot of layers eg 50-100 mono & stereo tracks, especially if it was for 5.1 predub/output....

Some gale force wind elements here:
http://hissandaroar.com/amb004-gale-force-wind

Comment: Thanks for the link. I could imagine it getting a bit out of hand if I was doing this for real for actual use but this is just part of my MSc project where I'm trying to demonstrate the possibilities of physical computing technology in film sound so I'm keeping it small scale - 4 layers of intensity of wind and rain, some thunder, some animal sounds. I may do a city scape version too and maybe I'll flesh it out into something more useable in the real world if it goes well.

Answer (score 0):

I've got one, but its rain on a carport.  Not sure if that would be useful to you or not.

Comment: I'm not totally sure if it would work but I'd definitely be interested in hearing it.